# Problem to use transaction in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that implements a transaction. I consume it through Entity Framework.

It works fine, but after calling it the first time, any other stored procedure that gets called afterwards fails. The exception says that the action is not allowed because the current session has a transaction started.

Thanks

Comment: You;ll need to add more detail, such as a copy of the Sproc in question. The issue seems pretty self-explanitory, that there is an execution path in your Sproc that begins a transaction without committing or rolling it back.

Comment: Problem solved. The entity object was static, i was change it.